# Android, parsing html, problem with strings in strings

Tags: java, android, html, string

Im trying to parse some html code line by line. However, when i search for a line that start with `<td class="departure"`, i cant manage to syntax it correctly because of the string delimiter signs (") (what is the name of this sign in english anyway?) in the html. It sees two strings and departure as a variable in between.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
if (line.startsWith("   <td class="departure"")){

   result += Html.fromHtml(line) + " ";
}
```

Comment: " is called a double quote or double quotation mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape that character (it's called quotes) by using `\`:

```
if (line.startsWith("   <td class=\"departure\"")){

   result += Html.fromHtml(line) + " ";
}
```

Comment: and just to make it even better don't rely on the amount of spaces (can be more or less than you expect) and those quotes (are optional) make the string more of a regex "[^\<]*<td class=\"?departure\"?" EDIT: my bad, startsWith doesn't allow regex, but then I'd consider going with if(line.matches("^[^\<]*<td class=\"?departure\"?")) { ...